# Вопрос по передаче данных между 2мя xml layouts

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня есть один XML, который я как шаблон хотел бы многократно использовать в другом основном XML. Насколько я понял, это можно сделать через include, и это работает.

Но возникает необходимость менять значение `android:text` у TextView, который находится внутри 1го шаблонного XML, для каждого нового блока внутри основного XML. Я пересмотрел уже кучу примеров в интернете и делаю через data binding так:

Шаблон, который многократно используется в основном XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="settingName"
            type="java.lang.String" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="24dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{settingName}"
            app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_drop_down_circle_24" />

        <com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Основной XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SettingsFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            layout="@layout/settingblocklayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:settingName='@{"Profile"}' />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/sport_kinds"
            layout="@layout/settingblocklayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:settingName='@{"Sport kind"}' />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

В Activity у меня код такой:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app);
    DataBindingUtil.setContentView(AppActivity.this, R.id.settingsFragment);
}
```

Причём есть проблема со строкой:

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(AppActivity.this, R.id.settingsFragment);
```

Без неё приложение запускается, но не работает binding и вместо текстовых строк "Profile" и "Sport" подтягивается пустая строка.

А с DataBindingUtil приложение не запускается и падает с ошибкой:

```
2021-08-15 21:09:08.045 12287-12287/com.eugvol.unitimer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.eugvol.unitimer, PID: 12287
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eugvol.unitimer/com.eugvol.unitimer.AppActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08018d type #0x12 is not valid
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08018d type #0x12 is not valid
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2406)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1252)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:530)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
        at com.eugvol.unitimer.AppActivity.onCreate(AppActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что не так.

Кстати, если вдруг есть ещё какой-либо способ кроме include, чтобы использовать один xml несколько раз внутри другого с изменением некоторых параметров первого xml (например, android:text у textview), то поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Спасибо!

Comment: В вашем вопросе сразу несколько проблем, переформулируйте так, чтобы ваш вопрос был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме. Касательно ошибки, вы, наверное, опечатались, в метод `setContentView` нужно передавать `R.layout`, а не `R.id`.

Comment: Vadik, спасибо! 
Да, действительно, одна досадная опечатка, которую искал весь день))

Answer (score 1):

Для тех, кто столкнётся с таким же вопросом, добавлю ещё маленький нюанс, который тоже мне пришлось долго самому искать.

Если байндинг нужно сделать на Activity, то в onCreate нужно вставить такую строку, на пример:

DataBindingUtil.setContentView(AppActivity.this, R.layout.activity_app);

А если нужно сделать байндинг на фрагменте (как было в моём случае), то в onCreateView нужно вставить такую:

View view = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false).getRoot();
ну, и конечно, потом return view; в этом методе.

Только не перепутайте R.id и R.layout, как я выше))